# Multiple Joins Working Independantly But Not Together

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am attempting to obtain a result of row information coming from tables named book_info and copy_info, and then (if they exist) results from a table named publisher(whose foreign key is in copy_info), and (if they exist) result from a table name genre via a junction table called books_genres. Below, $safe_copy_id is defined in a php statement, I left it in for the sake of the example. 

 
This works:

```
SELECT * FROM book_info, copy_info
LEFT OUTER JOIN publisher ON copy_info.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_id
WHERE book_info.book_id = copy_info.book_id
AND copy_info.copy_id = $safe_copy_id LIMIT 1
```

and this works:

```
SELECT * FROM book_info, copy_info, books_genres
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre ON books_genres.genre_id = genre.genre_id
WHERE book_info.book_id = copy_info.book_id
AND copy_info.copy_id = $safe_copy_id LIMIT 1
```

But what I would really like to work is this:

```
SELECT * FROM book_info, copy_info, books_genres
LEFT OUTER JOIN publisher ON copy_info.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre ON books_genres.genre_id = genre.genre_id
WHERE book_info.book_id = copy_info.book_id
AND copy_info.copy_id = $safe_copy_id LIMIT 1
```

Is it that I should be nesting something here? Not sure how to move forward and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That will probably fix your problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I removed the commas from the FROM clause. I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but I removed "LEFT OUTER" from each join clause to just say JOIN. This did not work unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure how the second query is working. There is no join condition for `books_genres` with either `book_info` or `copy_info`. Are you looking for cartesian product from `book_genres`? It would help if you give 2 rows for all the tables and your expected output based on that.

Comment: @Ustav I'm sorry, I have now realised the 2nd query is returning just the first result from the genre table no matter what the copy_id is. I will work to edit this to include a join condition. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JOIN` properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM book_info bi JOIN
     copy_info ci
     ON bi.book_id = ci.book_id JOIN
     publisher p
     ON ci.publisher_id = p.publisher_id JOIN
     books_genres bg
     ON bg.book_id = bi.book_id JOIN  -- your question doesn't specify the JOIN condition here
     genre g
     ON bg.genre_id = g.genre_id
WHERE ci.copy_id = $safe_copy_id
LIMIT 1;
```

You are missing a join to `book_genres`.  Perhaps it is linked to `book_info`.

Also, I see no reason to use outer joins for the query.  I suspect that all the tables have valid foreign key relationships.

Comment: You are correct that books_genres is linked to book info, I attempted to run this exact query with the ??'s replaced with the correct link and it is still failing. Thank you kindly for correcting my syntax though.

Comment: I have used outer joins because not every copy_id will have rows returned from the publisher or the genre tables. I'm not sure specifically why but it returns null if I use just JOIN, whereas if I use outer join, it's only returning null for the specific column (genre_id for an example). This is my best explanation of my experience, I don't if this is correct use of outer joins.

Comment: @KaariLandry . . . Seems reasonable.  Just replace all the `JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Gordon Linoff and Utsav for pointing out that I did not have a join to book_genres. Here is the query that actually worked:

```
 SELECT * FROM
book_info bi JOIN copy_info ci
 ON bi.book_id = ci.book_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN publisher p
 ON ci.publisher_id = p.publisher_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN books_genres bg
 ON bg.book_id = bi.book_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN genre g
 ON bg.genre_id = g.genre_id
WHERE ci.copy_id = $safe_copy_id
LIMIT 1;
```